# How can I avoid VSCode to open a new plot window?

Tags: r, visual-studio-code

I am setting up VSCode for R. Most of what I have right now works reasonably well. What still is a bit annoying to me is, that VSCode always opens a new window for a plot, if I make a change to it.

What I would like to do is:

- make a plot which ideally directly opens in my browser without opening a new VSCode window
- or make a plot, open it in external browser, close the window in VScode, and make changes without opening a VSCode window again .

I followed the instructions from [Ken Run](https://renkun.me/2022/03/06/my-recommendations-of-vs-code-extensions-for-r/) and also installed [httpgd](https://github.com/REditorSupport/vscode-R/wiki/Plot-viewer) but could not make VSCode to do what I want.

Comment: You may need to enable the R session watcher, as described here: https://github.com/REditorSupport/vscode-R/wiki/R-Session-watcher#basic-usage

Comment: @andycraig thank you for the feedback. I  have session watcher already enabled.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that a `.Rprofile` inside the project prevents a global one to be loaded.

It is also crucial to set the options right. With the following code in my *project*-`.Rprofile` I could get what I want:

- opening a plot directly in my browser without opening a plot inside VSCode.

```
if (interactive() && Sys.getenv("RSTUDIO") == "") {
  source(file.path(Sys.getenv(
    if (.Platform$OS.type == "windows") "USERPROFILE" else "HOME"
  ), ".vscode-R", "init.R"))
  if ("httpgd" %in% .packages(all.available = TRUE)) {
    options(vsc.plot = FALSE, vsc.use_httpgd = FALSE)
    options(device = function(...) {
      httpgd::hgd(silent = TRUE)
      .vsc.browser(httpgd::hgd_url(history = FALSE), viewer = FALSE)
    })
  }
}
```

Help came from [here](https://github.com/REditorSupport/vscode-R/issues/1182) and [REditorSupport](https://github.com/REditorSupport/vscode-R/wiki/R-Session-watcher#basic-usage). Thanks to @andycraig to point again to *R Session Watcher*.

Comment: Fantastic, this still works and frankly belongs on the vscode-R wiki